# How can hackers access WP usernames?

Tags: username, hacked, user-access

Recently I've had brute force attack attempts on some of my WordPress sites and the attackers are using actual usernames other than the default admin (which was removed).

How is it possible for them to know the usernames in a site's database without administrator privileges? (assuming they didn't get it from me directly using malware)

What are ways to prevent this from happening?

btw: All of my sites use the current version of WordPress.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Many themes `echo` the post author names associated with posts.
   Those are in some cases the same as the username.
2. The author archive links, depending on the permalink can reveal the
   username as well-- `/author/admin`

Getting the username is fairly trivial. I am sure there are other ways to manage it.

Comment: You forgot the user ID. ~99% people keep first `user ID 1` as their super Admin.